# subset a dataframe based on the columnnames of another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`. I want to subset `df1` such that the `colnames` of the subsetted `df1` are included in `colnames` of `df2`.

I know how to do it by using a for loop but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
df1_sub <- df1[,colnames(df1) %in% colnames(df2)]
```

Comment: df1_sub is then an empty dataframe. None of the columns is grabbed.

Comment: @Sepehr This code should work. Maybe we could see why it doesn't if you provided an example. Another version of this answer would be `df1[, intersect(names(df1), names(df2))]`

Comment: @Sepher, please share samples of df1 and df2 so we can check this  further.